# Android webView cannot handle pageFinish

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

If i return true on **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**, web view cannot handle **onPageFinish** when load new url.

```
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.abc.com")) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
              context.startActivity(intent);
              return true;
         }
         return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```

Disable progress on page finish.

```
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          super.onPageFinished(view, url);
          progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
```

Comment: I solved. it's happened because of using **pauseTimers()** in MyActivity **ondestroy()** method.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code

webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progressInt)
            {
                if (progressInt < 80 && progress.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE)
                {
                    progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (progressInt >= 80)
                {
                    progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Bu i must learn why i cannot handle pageFinish after shouldOverrideUrlLoading method return true. And i want to resolve this issue without use WebChromeClient.

Comment: @Muhammed: "Bu i must learn why i cannot handle pageFinish after shouldOverrideUrlLoading method return true". Because when returning true in shouldOverrideUrlLoading, you tell the current webview NOT to load the url, this means also no callbacks (onPageStarted, onPageFinished) are going to be invoked.                                 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)